# essential ideal of a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a well known fact:$A=\oplus_{i\in I}A_i$($c_0$ direct sum) is an essential ideal $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$($l^\infty$ direct sum),where each $A_i$ is a $C^*$ algebra.

I have two questions:

1.If $\oplus_{i\in I}A_i$ is an essential ideal of a $C^*$ algebra B, can we have B =$\prod_{i\in I}A_i$?

2.If $\oplus_{i\in I}A_i$ is an ideal of B,B has a faithful tracial state,can we conclude that $\oplus_{i\in I}A_i$ is an essential ideal of B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of the first question is no. Take $A_i = \mathbb C$. Then any compact space in which $\mathbb N$ embeds as a dense open set gives a $C^\ast$-algebra that contains $c_0$ as an essential ideal.

Similarly the second question has also a negative answer. Take $B$ as $\ell^\infty \oplus \mathbb C$. There is a faithful tracial state in $B$ but $c_0$ is not essential in $B$ (if you embed it in the first component)

Comment: Take a nontrivial convex combination of a faithful state of $\ell^\infty$ and the natural state of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: $\ell^\infty$ is Abelian, every state is tracial. To make a state faithful just take an element $g \in \ell^1$, positive and will full support.

Comment: No, but $\ell^1$ is inside the dual of $\ell^\infty$. Take the state $\phi((a_n)_n) = \sum_n 2^{-n} a_n$. If $a = (a_n)_n \in \ell^\infty$ is positive $\phi(a) = 0$ implies that $a_n = 0$ for every $n$.

Comment: No. It proves that $I$ is essential inside $M(I)$ not that if $I$ sits as an essential ideal of any other algebra, the algebra has to be $M(I)$.